# DB Connection - Singleton. How to pass users data in it?

Tags: php, pdo, parameters, singleton

Trying to use database connection with singleton. __constructor has been private and returning instance from static function.

```
class MyDbConn 
{
    protected $_conn;
    protected $database;
    protected $user;
    protected $password;
    protected $host = "localhost";
         private static $instance;

         private function __construct()
         {
              $this->db_conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->database",$this->user,$this->password);
              $this->db_conn->exec("set names utf8");
              $this->_conn = $this->db_conn;
         }

         public static function returnInstance() {
              if(self::$instance == null)
              {
                  print "Object  created!";
                  self::$instance = new self;

              }

               return self::$instance;

          }

           public function returnconnection(){
            return $this->_connection;
          }
     }
```

Now I can access the connection instance from MyDbConn::returnInstance()->returnconnection();

But,
How do I pass my users detail and database name to this constructor ?? I cannot do ::returnInstance($username,$password) or returnconnection($username,$password).

Any ideas please.

Comment: avoid using singleton pattern http://www.slideshare.net/go_oh/singletons-in-php-why-they-are-bad-and-how-you-can-eliminate-them-from-your-applications

Comment: @CodingInsane, I really don't think singleton is bad, if used in good sense. If you don't want multiple objects (Instances) to be created of a class, I believe, there is no better option than singleton. In my case, I need to limit the dbconnection instance, so your comment couldn't be helpful.

Comment: i can't see why you don't just use `Dependency Injection`

Comment: @CodingInsane, Dependency Injection is good idea, but based on my budget and nature of app, it will be "too much to do". So I am trying to go singleton. But I am always impressed with Dependency Injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `global` or with a normal function call

```
<?php
class MyDbConn 
{
    protected $_conn;
    protected $database;
    protected $user;
    protected $password;
    protected $host = "localhost";
    private static $instance;

    private function __construct()
    {

    }

    public static function returnInstance() {
         if(self::$instance == null)
         {
             print "Object  created!";
             self::$instance = new self;
         }
          return self::$instance;
     }

     private static function initDatabase(){
         $database = self::returnInstance();
         global $config;
         $database->_conn = new PDO("mysql:host={$config['host']};dbname={$config['database']}",$config['user'],$config['password']);
         $database->_conn->exec("set names utf8");
         return $database;
     }

      public static function returnconnection(){
       try {
           $db = self::initDatabase();
           return $db->_conn;
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
           echo "Error Establishing Database Connection " . $ex->getMessage();
           return null;
        }
      }
}
```

and pass the data like this

```
// will be called from initDatabase using global keyword
$config = array('host' => 'localhost', 'database' => 'db name','user' => 'user here','password' => '');

$db = MyDbConn::returnconnection();
```

I don't recommend Singleton, and i suggest using [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection)

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty basic question. You have your variables declared as protected which means that you can get them only inside the class. This is actually very good. To change these variables you need create get and set methods for example to change $user write methods:

```
public function setUser($user)
{
   $this->user = $user
}

public function getUser()
{
   return $this->user;
}

//Then you need get your object via

$db = MyDbConn::returnInstance();

//set user

$db->setUser('john');
```

and that's all. Moreover, singleton is call antipattern because it's hard to test and it's very similar to global variables which is not good.

Comment: Tried this before writing here. But As the dbconnection is made in constructor, it needs user already to be set, while calling
MyDbConn::returnInstance();
so setting user in next line didn't help.